# Vue3: update:modelValue using different data types for getter/setter

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I hope the title isn't too confusing, but to summarize, I wanted to create a DatePicker component.

I want the component to receive a 'string' (ie, '01/01/2023') which I want to convert to a object like:

```
{
  day: '01',
  month: '01',
  year: '2023'
}
```

Work with that object but when the value changes, the emit (ie, `update:modelValue`) is a string again.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<template>
  <div class="date-picker">
    <label
      class="date-picker__label"
      :for="key"
      >{{ label }}</label
    >
    <div class="date-picker__inputs">
      <div
        v-for="(key, index) in Object.keys(config)"
        :key="index"
      >
        <label
          class="date-picker__label"
          :for="key"
          >{{ key }}</label
        >
        <TextField
          v-model="model[key]"
          :class="key"
          :name="key"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'
import TextField from './TextField.vue'

const props = defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Date of Birth',
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '01/01/2023',
  },
  lang: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  dateOptions: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
    }),
  },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const config = computed(() => {
  let config = {}
  switch (props.lang) {
    case 'en-US':
      config = {
        month: {},
        day: {},
        year: {},
      }
      break
    case 'de-DE':
      config = {
        day: {},
        month: {},
        year: {},
      }
      break
  }

  return config
})

const model = computed({
  get: () => {
    const d = new Date(props.modelValue)

    const day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
    const month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
    const year = d.getFullYear().toString()

    if (d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
      return {
        day,
        month,
        year,
      }
    }

    return {
      day: '',
      month: '',
      year: '',
    }
  },
  set: (val) => {
    const d = new Date(val)

    if (d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
      emit(
        'update:modelValue',
        new Intl.DateTimeFormat(props.lang, props.dateOptions).format(
          new Date(d),
        ),
      )
    }
  },
})
</script>
```

the `model[key]` does not update the object therefore doesn't call the `set` function in the computed property. Anyone has any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just to remove the model's setter to a watch function with options {deep:true},
then you can watch the model[key]'s changes,and do what you want  do in setter

```js
< script setup >
  import {
    computed,
    watch
  } from 'vue'
import TextField from './TextField.vue'

const props = defineProps({
  label: {
    type: String,
    default: 'Date of Birth',
  },
  modelValue: {
    type: String,
    default: '01/01/2023',
  },
  lang: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  dateOptions: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({
      year: 'numeric',
      month: 'numeric',
      day: 'numeric',
    }),
  },
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const config = computed(() => {
  let config = {}
  switch (props.lang) {
    case 'en-US':
      config = {
        month: {},
        day: {},
        year: {},
      }
      break
    case 'de-DE':
      config = {
        day: {},
        month: {},
        year: {},
      }
      break
  }

  return config
})

const model = computed({
  get: () => {
    const d = new Date(props.modelValue)
    const day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
    const month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
    const year = d.getFullYear().toString()

    if (d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
      return {
        day,
        month,
        year,
      }
    }
    return {
      day: '',
      month: '',
      year: '',
    }
  }
})
watch(model, val => {
    const d = new Date(val)
    if (d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
      emit(
        'update:modelValue',
        new Intl.DateTimeFormat(props.lang, props.dateOptions).format(
          new Date(d)
        ),
      )
    }

  }, {
    deep: true
  }) 
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try some like instead of directly binding v-model to the nested object properties, use a temporary variable to hold the individual values of day, month, and year.  Something like this:

```
<template>
  <div class="date-picker">
    <label class="date-picker__label">{{ label }}</label>
    <div class="date-picker__inputs">
      <div v-for="(key, index) in Object.keys(config)" :key="index">
        <label class="date-picker__label">{{ key }}</label>
        <TextField
          v-model="tempValue[key]"
          :class="key"
          :name="key"
        />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed, ref } from 'vue'
import TextField from './TextField.vue'

const tempValue = ref({
  day: '',
  month: '',
  year: '',
})

const emit = defineEmits(['update:modelValue'])

const model = computed({
  get: () => {
    const d = new Date(props.modelValue)

    const day = d.getDate().toString().padStart(2, '0')
    const month = (d.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, '0')
    const year = d.getFullYear().toString()

    if (d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
      return {
        day,
        month,
        year,
      }
    }

    return {
      day: '',
      month: '',
      year: '',
    }
  },
  set: (val) => {
    const d = new Date(val)

    if (d instanceof Date && isFinite(d)) {
      emit(
        'update:modelValue',
        new Intl.DateTimeFormat(props.lang, props.dateOptions).format(
          new Date(d),
        ),
      )
    }
  },
})

watch(tempValue, (newVal, oldVal) => {
  const updatedModel = `${newVal.year}-${newVal.month}-${newVal.day}`
  model.value = updatedModel
})

const initialModel = model.value
tempValue.value = {
  day: initialModel.day,
  month: initialModel.month,
  year: initialModel.year,
}
</script>
```